# Heroku shared database not resetting

Tags: heroku

Trying to reset my Rails app's shared database on Heroku.

Doing the following appears to work.

```
heroku pg:reset SHARED_DATABASE --confirm rabid-raccoon-2000
```

I get: `Resetting SHARED_DATABASE (DATABASE_URL)... done`

And running `heroku run rake db:migrate` after that appears to work as well. But when I run `heroku run console`, or try to use the app, it does not reflect the changes (it still uses an ancient db schema- even right after I reset it).

I've tried this with both the free 5mb free db, as well as with the $15 shared db, both to no avail. No idea what db it's working with.

My database.yml is checked into version control, but I don't see how that can be a problem.

Comment: This is making me crazy as well... I'm almost to your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Just deleted the app and started over. Explanations are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought... I followed the directions [here](http://mutelight.org/heroku-postgres-dev) to set up a beta postgresql database.  The plus is that it gives me direct access to the database so I can change anything needed by my tables.

I then removed the generated .sql file with "git rm conf/evolutions/default/1.sql," committed and pushed to heroku.  Happily, the app is now working!

This issue is very frustrating, especially since it mostly affects people using Heroku for the first time (w/ the shared database).  It wasn't the database script since it worked just fine on the local dev database.  Hope this helps you out for next time.